# React: Inconsistent dataset value on MouseEvent.target

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Suppose I have a state `value` and it's being rendered as `data-value` in the DOM.

And the state is being changed by a `handleClick` function,

```
const handleClick = (e) => { 
   console.log(e.target) // it shows data-value: !value instead of value
   setValue(!value) 
   console.log(e.target)
}
```

Inside `handleClick` function, if I console e.target before changing the state, it shows the next state value even before changing the state.

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-frost-1qku6?file=/src/App.js

Comment: sometimes you can't trust console.log https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392111/console-log-async-or-sync

Answer (score 0):

IMO, this should never happen. You can probably try running the React app again or clear your browser cache. I changed your `handleClick` to this

```
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    console.log('Before calling setValue: ',e.target.dataset["value"], e.target); 
    setValue(!value);
    console.log('After calling setValue: ',e.target.dataset["value"], e.target);
}
```

Both logs the correct value of `value` on my console, ie, I see the previous state and not the updated state. So I get the expected behaviorur. `setValue` is asynchronous and the updated `value` should only be readable inside a `useEffect` that takes `value` as a dependency.

```
useEffect(()=>{
  console.log('Updated Value: ',value) 
},[value])
```

Anywhere inside `handleClick` the updated state will not be readable.